# $entityManager->flush() is not working - Symfony

Tags: symfony

I got a problem with my entityManager flush, it has been working on a page, trying to make it work on the other side of the many to many relation and I dont see what is missing, here is a part of my code:
ps: The password switch is working well

Form builder:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('Nom', TextType::class, [
            "label" => "Nom"
        ])
        ->add('Prenom', TextType::class, [
            "label" => "Prénom"
        ])
        ->add('Username', TextType::class, [
            "label" => "Identifiant"
        ])
        ->add('Password', RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'required' => false,
            'first_options' => [
                'label' => 'Mot de passe',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Modifier mot de passe')
            ],
            'second_options' => [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Confirmer mot de passe')
            ],
            'invalid_message' => 'Les mots de passes ne sont pas identiques.',
            // Instead of being set onto the object directly,
            // this is read and encoded in the controller
            'mapped' => false,
        ])
        ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Rôles',
            'multiple' => true ,
            'expanded' => true,
            'choices' => [
                'Utilisateur' => 'ROLE_USER',
                'Administrateur' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
            ],
        ])
        ->add('agendas', EntityType::class, [
            'class'=>'App:Agenda',
            'label'=>'Agendas attribué à l\'utilisateur',
            'choice_label' => 'nomAgenda',
            'expanded'=> true,
            'multiple' => true,
        ]);
}
```

a part of my entity:

```
  /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Agenda::class, mappedBy="Utilisateur")
 */
private $agendas;
/**
 * @return Collection|Agenda[]
 */
public function getAgendas(): Collection
{
    return $this->agendas;
}

public function addAgenda(Agenda $agenda): self
{
    if (!$this->agendas->contains($agenda)) {
        $this->agendas[] = $agenda;
        $agenda->addUtilisateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeAgenda(Agenda $agenda): self
{
    if ($this->agendas->removeElement($agenda)) {
        $agenda->removeUtilisateur($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

to end with my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/Modification/{id}", name="Modif", requirements={"id":"\d+"})
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
 * @param Request $request
 * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
 * @return Response
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function modifier($id, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
{
    $repoUtilisateur = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Utilisateur::class);
    $participant = $repoUtilisateur->find($id);
    //crée le formulaire en lui passant l'instance
    $profilForm = $this->createForm(ModifierFormType::class, $participant);
    //traitement des données
    $profilForm->handleRequest($request);
    //Traitement
    if ($profilForm->isSubmitted() && $profilForm->isValid()) {
        //on recupere la saisie du formulaire
        $participant = $profilForm->getData();
        $profilForm->get('agendas')->getViewData();

        // on reprend le mot de passe d'avant
        if ($participant->getPassword() == "") {
            $participant->setPassword($participant->getPassword());
        }
        //Modification du mot de passe
        if (!empty($profilForm->get('Password')->getData())) {
            // Encode the plain password, and set it.
            $encodedPassword = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $participant,
                $profilForm->get('Password')->getData()
            );
            $participant->setPassword($encodedPassword);
        }

        //insertion en base
        $entityManager->flush();

        //crée un message en session pour l'afficher sur la prochaine page
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Votre profil a bien été modifié');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('Utilisateur');
    }
    $this->addFlash('error', "Votre profil n'a pas pu etre modifié");
    return $this->render('Profil/Admin/modifierProfil.html.twig', [

        "modifier_profil_form" => $profilForm->createView()

    ]);
}
```

Comment: Area `Agenda`'s entity new entities, or already persisted to db?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forgot to persist the element ?
Add this before your flush

```
$entityManager->persist($participant)
```

Comment: Persist works only for new objects, if it's "update" operation - no need to call it. Check method description: "NOTE: The persist operation always considers objects that are not yet known to
     * this ObjectManager as NEW. Do not pass detached objects to the persist operation."